# How to convert a string to ObjectId in php mongodb native driver?

Tags: php, mongodb, codeigniter

I'm using MongoDB driver in a PHP environment (CodeIgniter framework) and I need to convert an id string to `ObjectId` to use it in my update query. How can I do this? I tried the following code but it is not working.

```
$collection->update(array('_id'=> $NewDeviceArray["myid"], $newdata);
```

I also tried a suggestion to convert the string into objectid, but that also failed.

```
$convertedid= new MongoId($NewDeviceArray["myid"]);
$collection->update(array('_id'=> $convertedid, $newdata);
```

***Update***

After correcting syntax error, this is the working code:

```
$collection->update(array('_id'=> $convertedid), $newdata);
```

Comment: your syntax is not correct `$collection->update(array('_id'=> $convertedid, $newdata)`, you missing brackets in the right places etc

Comment: I was so silly. I didn't see this small issue and messed up with the code for hours. Thank you @Sammaye.